# is there Multi Select Dynamic Dependent Select box using vanilla js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am having the problems with implementing the multi select in Dynamic Dependent Select box using vanilla js or jquery because most of the dynamic select are single select and I couldnt find any reference. I want to do like following example, you can check here http://demo.webslesson.info/muli-select-dynamic-dependent-dropdown-listbox/